# Sign a PDF using SmartCard

Tags: node.js, pdf, digital-signature, chilkat

I have tried to sign pdf using a smart card with Node JS **chilkat** but it fails.
and I found this error when I put the smart card and install here driver on my computer then I execute my code :
I cannot find the best solution

```
> TnTrust Token ChilkatLog:   LoadFromSmartcard(123984ms):
>     DllDate: Dec  2 2021
>     ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.89
>     UnlockPrefix: Auto unlock for 30-day trial
>     Architecture: Little Endian; 64-bit
>     Language: Windows Node.js
>     VerboseLogging: 1
>     NoScminidriver present in UncommonOptions
>       chosenCsp: TnTrust Token
>     --chooseSmartcardLegacyCsp
>     loadFromSmartcard_capi(3078ms):
>       loadSmartcardCert:
>         kcGetKpCertificate:
>           providerName: TnTrust Token
>           bExchangeKey: False
>           WindowsError: Acc�s refus�.
>           WindowsErrorCode: 0x80090010
>         --kcGetKpCertificate
>         retry with opposite choice...
>         kcGetKpCertificate:
>           providerName: TnTrust Token
>           bExchangeKey: True
>           WindowsError: Acc�s refus�.
>           WindowsErrorCode: 0x80090010
>         --kcGetKpCertificate
>         Unable to get the key provider certificate.
>       --loadSmartcardCert
>     --loadFromSmartcard_capi   --LoadFromSmartcard
> --ChilkatLog
```

also this :
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
when I run this code :

````
    var pdf = new chilkat.Pdf();
    var success = pdf.LoadFile("qa_data/pdf/hello.pdf");
    if (success == false) {
        console.log(pdf.LastErrorText);
        return;
    }
    var json = new chilkat.JsonObject();
    json.UpdateInt("signingCertificateV2",1);
    json.UpdateInt("signingTime",1);
    json.UpdateInt("page",1);
    json.UpdateString("appearance.y","top");
    json.UpdateString("appearance.x","left");
    json.UpdateString("appearance.fontScale","10.0");

    json.UpdateString("appearance.text[0]","Digitally signed by: cert_cn");
    json.UpdateString("appearance.text[1]","current_dt");
    var cert = new chilkat.Cert();
cert.UncommonOptions = "NoScMinidriver"
cspName = "TnTrust Token";
success = cert.LoadFromSmartcard(cspName)
    if (success == false) {
            console.log('TnTrust Token',cert.LastErrorText);
        return;
    }
    cert.SmartCardPin = "123456";
    success = pdf.SetSigningCert(cert);
    if (success == false) {
        console.log(pdf.LastErrorText);
        return;
    }
    success = pdf.SignPdf(json,"qa_output/hello_signed_hsm.pdf");
    if (success == false) {
        console.log(pdf.LastErrorText);
        return;
    }
    console.log("The PDF has been successfully cryptographically signed using an HSM.");
}

chilkatExample();```
thanks. 

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/11EwM.png
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uploaded a new build here:   https://www.npmjs.com/package/@chilkat/ck-node14-win64
It is the version "9.50.89-hotfix1".

Please give it a try.  Also, I see you are passing "TnTrust Token" to LoadFromSmartCard.  If the problem remains, try passing an empty string.  This should cause Chilkat to try using the default Microsoft CNG Storage Provider, which may have better success.

Comment: the error still the same

Comment: `LoadFromSmartcard(5313ms):
    DllDate: Feb 16 2022
    ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.89
    UnlockPrefix: Auto unlock for 30-day trial
    Architecture: Little Endian; 64-bit
    Language: Windows Node.js
    VerboseLogging: 1
    NoScminidriver present in UncommonOptions`

Comment: the last version help my life